# Visual studio server explorer server name could not be found

Tags: visual-studio

Found the feature, watched some guides and decided to start using data connections in my app. The problem is that db server is on the remote machine, and I can't connect to my server using ip address.

When I try to add new server it just says: server name "192.168.1.3" could not be found.

Really can't find much infomration about how does server connections works. I assume it uses ssh to connect(correct me if i'm wrong).

The server is 100% responding, can do ssh connection. Credentials are also fine.
Maybe the format is wrong, check this out:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYKnC.png)

Tried fiddler to figure out what's wrong, but it doesn't capture the requests.
Tried wireshark, found 2 pings of port 137, request size doesn't change depending on input data length, so it's nothing like login.

[packages screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sWtZ.png)
(only 1 ping, second is similar)

Am I doing something wrong? Maybe there are some alternatives? I can and do connect to my db using regular connection string, but seems like data connections in vs adds more flexibility.

Comment: Is the server of on the same network? 192.168.1.3 is a local address...

Comment: @tymtam yes, I know. It is in the same network and I can connect via ssh. Is it a problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.